# Update table using nested cursors in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update, cursor, dynamicquery

Kindly help me to optimize this code, or let me know if I can do this in a better way.

Req: I'm updating `Product` table which will have product info.

- The idea is to fetch some columns from other tables through join. (curTaxonomy is doing that.)
- And then update the fetched records to `Product` table.
- But before that I need to check if the columns which I'm updating in the `product` table are NULL or have dissimilar value (different value than what is coming from join).
- If these conditions match then only update the columns.

This I'm using cursors to fetch records and creating dynamic update query which will update the records.

CODE:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateProdCatalog]
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Tier_1_Tbl NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
DECLARE @Tier_2_Tbl NVARCHAR(100) = NULL    
DECLARE @Flag_Tbl NVARCHAR(100) = NULL

DECLARE @Tier_1 NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
DECLARE @Tier_2 NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
DECLARE @Flag NVARCHAR(100) = NULL  

DECLARE CurTaxonomy CURSOR FOR 
SELECT   CFR.T1, 
         CFR.T2, 
         CFR.Flag
FROM ProductCatalogue MPC
JOIN ControlFlow1 CF ON MPC.Product_Code = CF.Product_Code
JOIN ControlFlow2 CFR ON CF.MajorFamily = CFR.Product_Family
WHERE MPC.Manufacturer_Name = 'DELL';       

OPEN CurTaxonomy
IF @@CURSOR_ROWS > 0    
FETCH NEXT FROM CurTaxonomy INTO @Tier_1,@Tier_2,@Flag  
WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0        
    BEGIN           
    --print @Tier_1 + ' : '+ @Tier_2 + ' : '+ @Flag

        DECLARE CurProd CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT  MPC.Tier_1, 
                MPC.Tier_2, 
                MPC.Flag
        FROM ProductCatalogue MPC   
        WHERE MPC.Manufacturer_Name = 'DELL'

        OPEN CurProd
        IF @@CURSOR_ROWS > 0            
        FETCH NEXT FROM CurProd INTO @Tier_1_Tbl,@Tier_2_Tbl,@Flag_Tbl
        WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0        
            BEGIN                   
                --print @Tier_1_Tbl + ' : '+ @Tier_2_Tbl + ' : '+ @Flag_Tbl

                DECLARE @sqlCommand VARCHAR(8000)       
                DECLARE @Starter VARCHAR(100)

                --Generating dynamic update Query
                SET @Starter = 'SET '                   
                SET @sqlCommand = 'UPDATE ProductCatalogue '                
                BEGIN               
                    IF ( @Tier_1 IS NOT NULL) AND (@Tier_1_Tbl IS NULL or @Tier_1_Tbl <> @Tier_1) 
                        BEGIN   SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + @Starter + 'Tier_1 = ''' + @Tier_1 + ''''  SET @Starter = ', ' END
                    IF ( @Tier_2 IS NOT NULL)  AND (@Tier_2_Tbl IS NULL or @Tier_2_Tbl <> @Tier_2) 
                        BEGIN   SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + @Starter + 'Tier_2 = ''' + @Tier_2 + ''''  SET @Starter = ', ' END
                    IF ( @Flag IS NOT NULL) AND (@Flag_Tbl IS NULL or @Flag_Tbl <> @Flag) 
                        BEGIN   SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + @Starter + 'Flag = ''' + @Flag + ''''  SET @Starter = ', ' END  
                END             

                IF (@Starter = ', ')
                BEGIN           
                    SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + @Starter + ' Last_Modify_Date = ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(22),SYSDATETIME(),121) + '''' 
                    SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + ' FROM ProductCatalogue MPC 
                        JOIN ControlFlow1 CF ON MPC.Product_Code = CF.Product_Code
                        JOIN ControlFlow2 CFR ON CF.MajorFamily = CFR.Product_Family 
                        WHERE MPC.Manufacturer_Name = ''' + 'DELL' + ''''               

                    EXEC (@sqlCommand)
                END     

            FETCH NEXT FROM CurProd INTO @Tier_1_Tbl,@Tier_2_Tbl,@Flag_Tbl
        END
        CLOSE CurProd
        DEALLOCATE CurProd  

    FETCH NEXT FROM CurTaxonomy INTO @Tier_1,@Tier_2,@Flag
END
CLOSE CurTaxonomy
DEALLOCATE CurTaxonomy  
END
```

Here my concern is that the two cursors will run some ***n x m*** times and it is also updating the same value to all of the records. I even tried this which works fine.

```
update ProductCatalogue  
set Tier_1 = CFR.T1, 
    Tier_2 = CFR.T2, 
    Flag=CFR.Flag, 
    Last_Modify_Date = SYSDATETIME()
from ProductCatalogue MPC
join ControlFlow1 CF on MPC.Product_Code = CF.Product_Code
join ControlFlow2 CFR on CF.MajorFamily = CFR.Product_Family;
```

But I also need to check existing records in `product` table and fulfill the requirements as mentioned above .If there is any better way to do the same that'll be much appreciated.

Comment: You should try to do away with your cursors. You could use the OUTPUT clause of the UPDATE statement to output to a temp table that you could use to update your Product table. Please show us what you want to update in the product table.

Comment: @SteveFord : Hi Steve, I've mentioned that I need to update ,`Tier_1`, `Tier_2`, `Flag` and `Last_Modify_Date` values to `Product` table. That too when these columns are either null or have some different value than what we're getting from joining `Product`, `ControlFlow1` and `ControlFlow2` tables. Refer Select statement for cursor `CurTaxonomy ` for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this solution so far....But still the cursor execution will loop for ***N x M*** times.

CODE:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateProdCatalog]
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Product_Code_Tbl NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
    DECLARE @Tier_1_Tbl NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
    DECLARE @Tier_2_Tbl NVARCHAR(100) = NULL    
    DECLARE @Flag_Tbl NVARCHAR(100) = NULL  

    DECLARE @Product_Code NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
    DECLARE @Tier_1 NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
    DECLARE @Tier_2 NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
    DECLARE @Flag NVARCHAR(100) = NULL          

    DECLARE CurTaxonomy CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT   MPC.Product_Code,
             CFR.T1, 
             CFR.T2, 
             CFR.Flag
    FROM ProductCatalogue MPC
    JOIN ControlFlow1 CF ON MPC.Product_Code = CF.Product_Code
    JOIN ControlFlow2 CFR ON CF.MajorFamily = CFR.Product_Family
    WHERE MPC.Manufacturer_Name = 'DELL';       

    OPEN CurTaxonomy
    IF @@CURSOR_ROWS > 0    
    FETCH NEXT FROM CurTaxonomy INTO @Product_Code, @Tier_1,@Tier_2,@Flag   
    WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0        
        BEGIN                   
            DECLARE CurProd CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT  MPC.Product_Code,
                    MPC.Tier_1, 
                    MPC.Tier_2, 
                    MPC.Flag
                FROM ProductCatalogue MPC
                JOIN ControlFlow1 CF ON MPC.Product_Code = CF.Product_Code  
                JOIN ControlFlow2 CFR ON CF.MajorFamily = CFR.Product_Family
                WHERE MPC.Manufacturer_Name = 'DELL'

            OPEN CurProd
            IF @@CURSOR_ROWS > 0            
            FETCH NEXT FROM CurProd INTO @Product_Code_Tbl,@Tier_1_Tbl,@Tier_2_Tbl,@Flag_Tbl
            WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0        
                BEGIN               
                    DECLARE @sqlCommand VARCHAR(8000)       
                    DECLARE @Starter VARCHAR(100)

                    SET @Starter = 'SET '
                    SET @sqlCommand = 'UPDATE ProductCatalogue '

                    if (@Product_Code IS NOT NULL) AND (@Product_Code_Tbl = @Product_Code)
                    BEGIN           

                        IF ( @Tier_1 IS NOT NULL) AND (@Tier_1_Tbl IS NULL or @Tier_1_Tbl <> @Tier_1) 
                            BEGIN   SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + @Starter + 'Tier_1 = ''' + @Tier_1 + ''''  SET @Starter = ', ' END
                        IF ( @Tier_2 IS NOT NULL) AND (@Tier_2_Tbl IS NULL or @Tier_2_Tbl <> @Tier_2) 
                            BEGIN   SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + @Starter + 'Tier_2 = ''' + @Tier_2 + ''''  SET @Starter = ', ' END
                        IF ( @Flag IS NOT NULL) AND (@Flag_Tbl IS NULL or @Flag_Tbl <> @Flag) 
                            BEGIN   SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + @Starter + 'Flag = ''' + @Flag + ''''  SET @Starter = ', ' END  
                    END                 

                    IF (@Starter = ', ')
                    BEGIN           
                        SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + @Starter + ' Last_Modify_Date = ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(22),SYSDATETIME(),121) + '''' 
                        SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand +  ' WHERE Product_Code = ''' + @Product_Code + ''' and Manufacturer_Name = ''' + 'DELL' + ''''                   
                        EXEC (@sqlCommand)
                    END     

                FETCH NEXT FROM CurProd INTO @Product_Code_Tbl,@Tier_1_Tbl,@Tier_2_Tbl,@Flag_Tbl
            END
            CLOSE CurProd
            DEALLOCATE CurProd  

        FETCH NEXT FROM CurTaxonomy INTO @Product_Code, @Tier_1,@Tier_2,@Flag   
    END
    CLOSE CurTaxonomy
    DEALLOCATE CurTaxonomy  
END
GO
```